# How to implement CardDAV in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, icloud, carddav

I want to import contacts from from iCloud and I know it can be done through CardDAV protocol which used by iCloud at server side. But how I can fetch contacts from iCloud using CardDAV, is there any gem to perform such operation or code.

Any help and suggestion really encouraging.

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?q=carddav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [dav4rack_ext](https://github.com/schmurfy/dav4rack_ext). It seems to do what you are looking for.

No direct experience with it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [carddav gem](https://github.com/timsly/carddav)

It has built-in iCloud support

```
service = Carddav.service(:apple, 'email@icloud.com', 'password')
service.cards
```